# java.lang.UnsatisfieldlinkError: Native method not found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to build a demo app using jni (I am new to it). I have Googled and SO about the problem but nothing helped.

Below is the code I am using:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := example
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_example_Operacoes.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Operacoes.java
    package com.example.example;

```
public class Operacoes {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("example"); 
}   

//Versao nativa do metodo soma
public static native int soma(int a, int b);

//Versao nativa do metodo subtracao
public static native int sub(int a, int b);

    }
```

com_example_example_Operacoes.h

```
   # include "com_example_example_Operacoes.c"

   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_soma (JNIEnv *, jclass,          jint, jint);

   int soma(int a, int b){
return a + b;
   }


  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_sub (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint,  jint);
   int sub(int a, int b){
return a - b;
  }
```

com_example_example_Operacoes.h

```
  /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
  #include <jni.h>
  /* Header for class com_example_example_Operacoes */

  #ifndef _Included_com_example_example_Operacoes
  #define _Included_com_example_example_Operacoes
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif
  /*
  * Class:     com_example_example_Operacoes
  * Method:    soma
  * Signature: (II)I
  */
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_soma (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

  /*
  * Class:     com_example_example_Operacoes
  * Method:    sub
  * Signature: (II)I
  */
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_sub (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  #endif
```

Comment: Check whether you have successfully generated the .SO file in the lib dir.Without the .so file it will not run properly

Answer (score 1):

You are not implementing the functions.  Notice your first line(below), you have a semi colon on the end of the line.  Then you create a second function with a different format `int soma(int,int)`

```
...Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_soma (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);<<<wrong
```

You need to implement the native function using the exact same format as declared.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_example_Operacoes_soma (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jint a, jint b)
{
     return a + b;
}
```